# What's the purpose of peerAddresses

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm using [the test network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/test-network).

`peer chaincode invoke` can take option `--peerAddresses` that I choose one or more peers to execute the chaincode. ([ref](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-invoke))

Following [the test network tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html), if I run InitLedger on two peers, the command throws error.

> $ peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride
> orderer.example.com --tls --cafile
> ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
> -C mychannel --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt 
> --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt 
> --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt 
> -C mychannel -n basic -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
>
> Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500
> message:"error in simulation: failed to execute transaction
> 2b3d3a615c2fd99e2503779cc25f923a54103997883548a92184423e67df93a2:
> error sending: txid:
> 2b3d3a615c2fd99e2503779cc25f923a54103997883548a92184423e67df93a2(mychannel)
> exists"

When will I run commands on two peers?

It looks like the network will "[compares the proposal responses to determine if the proposal responses are the same](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/txflow.html)". In that case why do I need to specify a peer given other peers will execute the command again to verify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending the same transaction twice to the same peer `localhost:7051`. Remove one of those peerAddresses/tlsRootCertFiles pairs.

Every transaction must fulfill the [endorsement policies](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/endorsement-policies.html) of the chaincode. If not specified during chaincode instantiation, in Fabric 2.X (with a regular `configtx.yaml`) the default endorsement policy requires the endorsement of peers from N/2 + 1 organizations (where N is the number of organizations in the channel).

The client is the responsible to demand those endorsements through transaction proposals and gather all the proposals in a single transaction. With `peerAddresses` your client specifies the peers used in this process.

After the endorsement, the client sends the transaction to the ordering service to be embedded in a block and the block is delivered to all the peers joined to the channel to be commited to the ledger. Committing peers check again that proposals match (since now it had been only checked by the client) and that all transactions include the required signatures. But they don't execute/simulate again the chaincode operation, that was already done during endorsement. And then, the ledger is updated. It is quite well explained in https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/txflow.html.

In your case, the problem is that you are sending the transaction twice to `localhost:7051`. You must send your transaction only once to each peer. Once to `localhost:7051` and once to `localhost:9051`, for instance. Look at the **bold** text in this command copied from your original post.

$ peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel **--peerAddresses localhost:7051** --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
--peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
**--peerAddresses localhost:7051** --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
-C mychannel -n basic -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'

Comment: Can you show me the code where `--peerAddresses` appears twice?

Comment: At the end of my edit.

Answer (score -1):

In a nutshell, your command has `--peerAddresses` appeared THREE times instead of two.